# Reusing malloc to pass different pointers to signal handlers

Tags: c, gtk, malloc, glib

In the following code block, I create a pointer to a struct so I can supply multiple variables to a gtk signal handler, which is set to automatically `g_free()` the struct when the handler is disconnected.

The second part `malloc`s the variable again and sends the new pointer to the new signal handler. Will this work?

Just from reading it I presume it will leave the first struct data in place at the pointer, and create a new pointer I can change the data in later, all while properly disposing of the memory later.

Knowing that `malloc` is hardly so simple, I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing, or should take into account.

```
signaldata * s;
s = (signaldata *) g_malloc(sizeof(signaldata *));
s->col = 0; s->secondaryCol = -1; s->model = GTK_TREE_MODEL(itemModel);
g_signal_connect_data(firstWidget,"edited",(GCallback) treeview_text_edited,s, (GClosureNotify) g_free, 0);

s = (signaldata *) g_malloc(sizeof(signaldata *));
s->col = 1; s->secondaryCol = -1; s->model = GTK_TREE_MODEL(itemModel);
g_signal_connect_data(secondWidget,"edited",(GCallback) treeview_text_edited,s, (GClosureNotify) g_free, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be OK because the pointer itself is copied before calling `g_signal_connect_data`, so it doesn't matter that later you assign it a new address by doing a second `g_malloc`.

However, you lose your only reference to the first `g_malloc`'d memory (unless somehow it becomes accessible from `firstWidget`) and that can be undesirable if you want to do any further manual manipulation to it.

Comment: Nope, just needed to know the signals would work and I wouldn't get a memory leak. Thank!

Comment: the memory will still be accessible from the signal handler `treeview_text_edited()`, which is where it is needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there will be a memory leak if the signal is never used.

That may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: It may, but why would it? The data is `free`d when the signal handler is disconnected, which would happen after a `gtk_main_quit` right?